# Does Windows recognize symlinks created under Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, virtualbox, symbolic-link

Before, I dual installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. They shared a Windows ntfs partition by mounting the partition under Ubuntu. I don't remember if the symlinks created under Ubuntu could be recognized by Windows.

Now, I have Windows 8.1 running inside VirtualBox in Ubuntu 14.04. I also installed some guest addition on the virtual machine for windows for sharing folder. In the shared folder, I found that the Windows can follow the symlinks created on an ext4 filesystem under Ubuntu. Why does that work? Is it

- because Windows can recognize symlinks of Linux, (just it would on dual boot? but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231095/will-symbolic-links-created-in-unix-linux-osx-still-working-in-windows) says no?)
- or because the shared folder is mounted as a network drive,
- or because of VirtualBox or the guest addition?

Thanks.

Comment: I expect it is something to do with the VirtualBox guest additions - normally this would not work.

Answer (score 3):

When running inside a VM, Windows does not have direct access to the host's filesystem, which contains your shared folder (actually, if that was possible it would most certainly destroyed the filesystem when two OSes tried to write data to it).

Instead, VirtualBox (guest additions) provides a translation layer between your guest OS and the host filesystem. From the host's point of view, VirtualBox is just another user-space application which reads and writes to the filesystem using kernel's system calls, so it does not care about the actual filesystem type as long as kernel understands it.

For Windows (or another host OS) it looks like a network drive, so it can access the data as it would on any other network drive.